# How can I insert an array into my MongoDB stitch if I already have IDs defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I get my data from an API and I parse the JSON object which leads to an array. [{ id: "24qera", name: "john"}, {id: "rq3raa34", name: "jess"}}. I have over 20 documents which I am trying to store.

I have my array called data and my db variable connected to my database and my collection connected as well. I use the line `collection.insertMany( json );` When I use that, I now have two IDs which is my objectID and my array ID.

````
    var db = dbService.db("GitLab-db");
    var collection = db.collection("User");

    collection.insertMany(fdata);```

expectation: {
          _id:ObjectId("24qera"),
           name: "john"
         },
         {
          _id:ObjectId("rq3raa34"),
           name: "jess"
          }


output: {
          _id:ObjectId("jfakej23j4q3wa4")
           id: "24qera",
           name: "john"
         },
         {
          _id:ObjectId("akjk34qq453")
           id: "rq3raa34",
           name: "jess"
          }
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cant really manipulate the _id which is auto generated by mongodb on storing the data in array....you can just ignore the _id and work with the id which is being stored

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB automatically inserts an `_id` value if not provided. This is hard-coded behavior to ensure that there is *always* a unique primary key available for retrieving specific documents. You cannot change this behavior.

You can, however, simply ignore the `_id` field, or even strip it out completely from returned results by adding a projection option. For example, in the MongoDB shell you can run the following:

```
db.User.find({name: "jess"}, {_id: 0})
```